# Automatic scrolling when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The jQuery UI Draggable plugin makes selected elements draggable by mouse.
Here an [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/sortable.html).

Let's suppose the list is longer than vertical screen size.
The 'scroll bar' allows you to see other parts of a web page that are not being shown on the screen.

If you click and drag an item across the bottom of the page I would like the vertical scroll bar to move in order to see the hidden items lists..
How can I make it using jQuery UI Draggable or a piece of javascript code?

Comment: What is your browser? All of my browsers (IE8, Chrome20, FF12 and Maxthon3) automatically scroll the page while I'm dragging one of the items out of the viewport!!

Comment: @gopi1410 it wasn't me. For sure your answers are rights and the problem is in my html/css/js code. I will try to reproduce the problem in jsfidlle. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [jqueryui documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) by default the scroll option is set to `true`.

Code examples:

```
// if you want to disable the scroll option
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ scroll: false });
```

If it does not work the problem should be had to something else, your html/css/javascript code for example.
Could you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?